SVN diff between a particular revision of a file and and external file
I wanted to get a diff output between a particular revision of a versioned file and an external file.
I understand this is possible svn diff --old "path/to/versioned/file1"@1234 --new "path/to/versioned/file1"@1235 find the differences between revision 1234 and 1235 of the file.
And also this svn diff --old "path/to/versioned/file1" --new "externalpath/to/external/folder/file1" which finds the difference between the latest versioned file and an external file which is not versioned with SVN.
What I wanted was to compare a particular revision against and external file which is not versioned.
Something like this:
svn diff --old "path/to/versioned/file1"@1234 --new "externalpath/to/external/folder/file1"
Edit:
The issue is that that command does not work.
Error text:
svn: E155007: 'externalpath/to/external/folder/file1' is not a working copy

FYI: I am using TortoiseSVN as the SVN client

Edited to include error I received

@friedrich's workaround does work well for this particular query.
One alternative workaround I used which can prevent the need to update the database is to cat the required revision to a file using the command svn cat "path/to/versioned/file1"@1234 > file1234 and diff-ing with that temporary file. The entire one line command looks as such:
svn cat "path/to/versioned/file1"@1234 > file1234 & svn diff --old file1234 --new externalpath/to/external/folder/file1

You swapped old and new compared to your question.

I can reproduce the behavior with svn CLI.
Quoting from svn help diff:

Either or both OLD-TGT and NEW-TGT may also be paths to unversioned targets. Revisions cannot be specified for unversioned targets.

I found the diff to work as soon as I omitted the revision specifier.
It seems that specifying a revision for either target prevents use with an unversioned target.
This may be a bug in Subversion and you should raise it on its issue tracker.
As a workaround, you can svn update the versioned target to the revision to compare and leave out the revision specifier from svn diff:
svn update -r1234 path/to/versioned/file1
svn diff --old path/to/versioned/file1 --new externalpath/to/external/folder/file1
svn update path/to/versioned/file1

Don't forget to update your versioned file after you've done comparing.

That is a good workaround and does solve the initial query I had. The reason why I wanted it to compare with a revision directly is because I will have local modifications to the database in my system which will be gone by this revert of revision and updating back.

I did find an alternative workaround which might work.
The workaround is to cat the particular revision to a file: file1234 and then diff with that file as such
svn cat "path/to/versioned/file1"@1234 > file1234 & svn diff --old externalpath/to/external/folder/file1 --new file1234

@Amazonian_panda looks good. You could add an answer of your own with your workaround.
